# Can't get to value inside XML spanclass

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to retrieve a value in one of the spanclasses in an online XML-file.

File: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

I want to get to the USD rate but my code does not seem to loop through and span-classes, where is my mistake?

My code

```
Function response_Text(url As String) ' get the responsetext from an xml request

Dim xml As Object
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With xml
    .Open "Get", url, False
    .send
    response_Text = .responsetext
    End With

Set xml = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub find_ClassElement(HTML_doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument) ' return value inside span_class

Dim ticker As Variant
Dim XML_elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim XML_spanclass As MSHTML.HTMLSpanElement
Dim XML_targetElement As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement

Set XML_elements = HTML_doc.getElementsByClassName("line") **<--- something seems to be wrong here, the code does not loop through any span_classes after this point as intended ( the for statement is not being executed )**

For Each XML_spanclass In XML_elements
    If InStr(XML_spanclass.innerHTML, "USD") > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "success"
        Set XML_targetElement = XML_spanclass.parentElement
        Debug.Print CSng(XML_targetElement.getElementsByClassName("webkit-html-attribute-value")(0).innerHTML)
    End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub run() ' run the whole operation

Dim http_req As http_req: Set http_req = New http_req
Dim xml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set xml = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim url As String: url = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

xml.body.innerHTML = http_req.response_Text(url)

Call find_ClassElement(xml)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tags with a class of "line" so your collection is empty - nothing to loop through.  Here's another way

```
Sub GetUSD()

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xCube As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim xCubes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection
    Dim sCurrency As String

    'load the xml document
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    xDoc.Load "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

    'wait until it's completely loaded
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until xDoc.readyState = 4

    'get all the cube tags
    Set xCubes = xDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cube")

    For Each xCube In xCubes
        'some cube tags don't have attributes
        On Error Resume Next
            sCurrency = xCube.Attributes(0).Text
        On Error GoTo 0

        'if the first attribute is USD, get the second attribute
        If sCurrency = "USD" Then
            Debug.Print xCube.Attributes(1).Text
        End If
    Next xCube

End Sub
```

**edit**

I don't know xpath well enough to do this properly, but this works.

```
Sub GetUSD()

    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xCube As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xCubes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim sCurrency As String

    'load the xml document
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xDoc.Load "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

    'wait until it's completely loaded
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until xDoc.readyState = 4

    'get all the cube tags
    Set xCubes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//*")

    For Each xCube In xCubes

        On Error Resume Next
            sCurrency = xCube.Attributes(0).NodeValue
        On Error GoTo 0

        'if the first attribute is USD, get the second attribute
        If sCurrency = "USD" Then
            Debug.Print xCube.Attributes(1).NodeValue
        End If
    Next xCube

End Sub
```

Comment: Nevertheless, I do see a line that is the following: <div class = "line">

But this is not a clasS?

Comment: I tried your code but it won't work. For some reason I can only create an IXMLDOMElement60 and I get an http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251663(v=office.15).aspx error when trying to load the XML file onto the DOMDocument by the following code: DOMDocument.load = "website.xml"

Comment: I see no div tags at all in that file. I don't think we're using the same file. I'm using the one that you linked to in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm right-clicking on the XML-code in the browser and selecting "show componenets" to get the HTML tags... but of course this sounds very silly compared to loading the document and then using a parser / DOM.

Comment: I notice you use the older XML 3.0 version, could you maybe be so kind as to provide a solution compatible with XML 6.0 version? 

I there any major benefits with executing in XML 3.0 and why does some of the methods that work in XML 3.0 not work in XML 6.0?